# Delete subelement from xml file in python

Tags: python, xml

I am getting to learn how to modify in xml file using python and lxml library and ElementTree.
After some work I have as result this xml file:

```
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.orgr">
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
      <peripheral>
        <name>periph</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
        <range>0x8</range>
        <width>32</width>
        <register>
          <name>reg1</name>
          <displayName>reg1</displayName>
          <description>This is register 1</description>
          <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
          <size>32</size>
          <access>read-write</access>
          <resetValue>0x00000002</resetValue>
          <resetMask>0xFFFFFFFF</resetMask>
         <fields>
           .................
         </fields>
         <resetValue>0x00000002</resetValue>
         <resetMask>0xFFFFFFFF</resetMask>
         <description>This is register 1</description>
        </register>                           
        <register>
              .................
         </register>
         <register>
             ..................
         </register>      
      </peripheral>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>
```

what I did here is for each 'register' node I created three new subelements ('*resetValue*' , '*resetMask*' and '*description*') using function *ET.SubElement* , and later on I copied them above in new positions using *element.insert* , but now I need to delete the extra ones from the end of register node to have it look like this:

```
<register>
      <name>reg1</name>
      <displayName>reg1</displayName>
      <description>This is register 1</description>
      <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
      <size>32</size>
      <access>read-write</access>
      <resetValue>0x00000002</resetValue>
      <resetMask>0xFFFFFFFF</resetMask>
     <fields>
       .................
     </fields>
  </register>
```

I know maybe it wasn't the best approach to create subelement, then replace it in new position and now try to delete, but when I looked another function called *ET.Element* and then *insert*, but I had difficulties with locating index of correct position so I choose this method.

Here I am listing a part of my code that I used here(I extracted text for my subelements from other elements):

```
   v =  ET.SubElement(register, 'resetValue')
   v.text = value 
                                                                                                       
   m = ET.SubElement(register, 'resetMask')  
   m.text = mask 
                                                                                                           
   displayName = register.find('.//displayName').text
   d = ET.SubElement(register, 'description')
   d.text = displayName 
                                                                                   
   register.insert(5, v)  
   register.insert(6, m)                                                                             
   register.insert(2, d)
```

(I hope this code portion clears more the problem)

Can someone advise me please!

Comment: Give your code as an example, others will be able to understand your ideas more clearly.

Comment: I added a portion of code to clear what I did as steps...hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML parsing library, which is not professional enough in modification, but flexible. Here is an example for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import SimplifiedDoc
xml = '''
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.orgr">
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
      <peripheral>
        <name>periph</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
        <range>0x8</range>
        <width>32</width>
        <register>
          <name>reg1</name>
          <displayName>reg1</displayName>
          <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
          <size>32</size>
          <access>read-write</access>
          <fields>
          .................
          </fields>
        </register>   
      </peripheral>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)  # create doc
registers = doc.selects('register')

l = len(registers)
while l > 0:
    l = l - 1
    register = registers[l] # Start at the back. If you modify it from the front and continue to modify it on the basis of changing the structure of the document, the results may not meet the expectations.

    v = doc.createElement('resetValue', str(l))
    m = doc.createElement('resetMask', str(l))
    d = doc.createElement('description', 'This is register '+str(l))

    access = register.access
    access.insertAfter('\n' + ' ' * 10 + m) # Handling line breaks and padding
    access.insertAfter('\n' + ' ' * 10 + v)

    displayName = register.displayName
    displayName.insertAfter('\n' + ' ' * 10 + d)

print(doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.orgr">
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
      <peripheral>
        <name>periph</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
        <range>0x8</range>
        <width>32</width>
        <register>
          <name>reg1</name>
          <displayName>reg1</displayName>
          <description>This is register 0</description>
          <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
          <size>32</size>
          <access>read-write</access>
          <resetValue>0</resetValue>
          <resetMask>0</resetMask>
          <fields>
          .................
          </fields>
        </register>   
      </peripheral>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help but I am still unable to use this as solution. I would hope for a solution to work with the lxml library :(

Comment: I understand you, but I don't know how to do this with lxml. I hope someone can help you.